# jQuery blueimp file upload with POST data

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to allow my users to upload multiple files using the blueimp plugin.  After the file is uploaded, I need to add it to a hidden field in the form, so that when i post the form to the processing page, the file names will be captured in the form data.

```
var a = 0;
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url:'actions/Tickets/uploads/server/php/',
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
            a++;
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
               $('#files\\['+a+'\\]').val(file.name);
            });
    }
 });
```

The part of the form im trying to add to (id=files[]).

```
<td><input type='file' id='fileupload' multiple></td>
<input type='hidden' id='files[]' name='files[]' >
```

i serialize the form and post.  I have tried various methods, but can not get the POST array to show the files uploaded.

process.php

```
   print_r($_POST);

   [files] => Array ( [0] => ) )
```

the goal would be:

```
    [files] => Array ( [0] => 'somefile.txt',[1]=>'someOtherfile.txt')
```

I cant figure out how to get the POST Data to contain all the files uploaded...How can i acheive this?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: edited.  how can i get the post data to contain the files uploaded.

Comment: Use the $_FILES array. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php